# Optimize "= any" operator using index

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5. I have a table with column of array type.

```
create table test (
  id serial primary key,
  arr text[] not null
)
```

Now I want to issue a query like

```
select id from test where 'value' = any(arr)
```

This query uses full-scan. I need to optimize it, because table might be large and 'value' occurs only on a few rows.

I tried to create index:

```
create index on test(arr);
```

But postres still uses full-scan.

If I rewrite query to

```
select id from test where array['value'] = arr;
```

then it uses index, but it's a different query. I think it happens, because postgres indexes array value as a whole. Is it possible to index individual array items?

I understand that I could make two tables with one-to-many relationship, but I need this structure.

Comment: Have you tried creating a GIN index rather than a BTREE index?

Comment: Yep, it seems that I needed GIN index, thanks.